# Check if n consecutive elements equals x and any previous element is greater than x

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe with 6 mins readings. I want to mark each row as either NF or DF.
NF = rows with 5 consecutive entries being 0 and at least one prior reading being greater than 0
DF = All other rows that do not meet the NF rule

```
[[4,6,7,2,1,0,0,0,0,0]
 [6,0,0,0,0,0,2,2,2,5]
 [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
 [0,0,0,0,0,4,6,7,2,1]]
```

Expected Result:

```
[NF, NF, DF, DF]
```

Can I use a sliding window for this? What is a good pythonic way of doing this?

Comment: Please go through the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) and [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)  to see how this site works and to help you improve your current and future questions, which can help you get better answers.
"Show me how to solve this coding problem?" is off-topic for Stack Overflow.
You have to make an honest attempt at the solution, and then ask a *specific* question about your implementation.
Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing tutorials and documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- using staring numpy vectorised solution, two conditions operating on truth matrix
- uses fact that **True** is **1** so `cumsum()` can be used
- position of 5th zero should be 4 places higher than 1st
- if you just want the array, the `np.where()` gives that without assigning if back to a dataframe column
- used another test case `[1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0]` where there are many zeros, but not 5 consecutive

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[4,6,7,2,1,0,0,0,0,0],
 [6,0,0,0,0,0,2,2,2,5],
 [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
 [1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0],
 [0,0,0,0,0,4,6,7,2,1]])

df = df.assign(res=np.where(
    # five consecutive zeros
    ((np.argmax(np.cumsum(df.eq(0).values, axis=1)==1, axis=1)+4) == 
     np.argmax(np.cumsum(df.eq(0).values, axis=1)==5, axis=1)) &
    # first zero somewhere other that 0th position
    np.argmax(df.eq(0).values, axis=1)>0
    ,"NF","DF")
)
```

|  | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | res |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 4 | 6 | 7 | 2 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | NF |
| 1 | 6 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 5 | NF |
| 2 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | DF |
| 3 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | DF |
| 4 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 4 | 6 | 7 | 2 | 1 | DF |